# Angular Table With Spacing

Tags: html, css, angular

Below is the code sample I tried coding it out in Angular but it's not something that I want.

```
                    <table>
                        <th >No.</th>
                        <th >Merchant </th>
                        <th >Last Order Grand Total </th>
                        <th >Last Order Date </th>
                        <hr>
                          <tr *ngFor="let item of topFiveActiveMerchant; index as i;">
                            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.merchant_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.merchant_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.created_date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a'}}</td>
                          </tr>
                    </table>
```

I want it to be something like this
[image: Want this design]

but i ended up with
[image: Ended up with this]

Comment: Are you looking for the formatting for the Merchant column? or the horizontal row below the table header.

Comment: If you want to format the table you can try bootstrap class: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Comment: Please provide `topFiveActiveMerchant` infos

Comment: @TanYiJing Please check my answer and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use simple table I have a solution for you. However, I think you check `mat-table` ([Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)). It is easy and a lot of features are available in `mat-table`. Now, here is my code for simple table below=> ([Full Demo Code Available in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emscb3?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.css)).

**HTML:**

```
<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table headers">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of config">{{column.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="my-table body">
    <tr my-active *ngFor="let row of data.data; index as rowIndex">
      <td (click)="onSelect(rowIndex)" *ngFor="let column of config; index as i" [ngClass]="{last: i === (config.length - 1) }">{{row[column.value]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export const configColumns = [{
  header: "Name",
  value: "name"
}, {
  header: "E-mail",
  value: "email"
}, {
  header: "Phone",
  value: "phone"
}];
export const data = [{
  name: "John Doe 1",
  email: "johndoe_one@email.com",
  phone: "900001111"
}, {
  name: "John Doe 2",
  email: "johndoe_two@email.com",
  phone: "900002222"
}, {
  name: "John Doe 3",
  email: "johndoe_three@email.com",
  phone: "900003333"
}];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
   data:any;
   config:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.config=configColumns;
    this.data=data;
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
table.my-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

thead.my-table.headers tr th {
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
}

tbody.my-table.body tr td {
  border: black solid 1px;
 
  height: 25px;
}

tbody.my-table.body tr.active {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.pag-space {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

button.pag-button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

select.size-page {
  width: 100px;
  text-align-last: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be actually using the table component from Angular Material but the table's styles.

Comment: I  did not use `mat-table` because Question was for normal table. For `mat-table` it can be done easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/) you can use those tables. If you want to build custom table then you need to style every element of the table.

To style each column in `Table Header` and `Table Description` you can use the following `css` to style it.

In your `component.html` template. add `class` to the table.

```
<table class="custom-table">
```

In your `component.css` or `component.scss`

```
.custom-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.custom-table th,
.custom-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    // other css
}
```

Separate header styling

```
.custom-table th {
    padding: 10px;
    // other css
}
```

Separate column styling

```
.custom-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    // other css
}
```

To specify width of a column.

```
<th style="width: 200px">Merchant</th>
```

Other styles

```
<th style="width: 200px; text-align: center">Merchant</th>
```

same for column description.

```
<td style="text-align: center">{{item.merchant_name}}</td>
```

Styling within column description

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    <div class="name">{{item.merchant_name}}</div>
    <div class="desg">{{item.merchant_desg}}</div>
</td>
```

Follow styling guide of angular [component-styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

```
::ng-deep .custom-table .name {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    // other styles
}
::ng-deep .custom-table .desg {
    font-size: 12px;
    // other styles
}
```

Using `SCSS`

```
::ng-deep .custom-table {
    .name {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        // other styles
    }
    .desg {
        font-size: 12px;
        // other styles
    }
}
```